# Фейковый визит сайта python

Tags: python, парсер

Имеется сокращенная ссылка на bit.ly
Код делает запрос на сокращенную ссылку, и по идее клик должен засчитываться в статистике, но этого не происходит. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

```
header = {'authority': 'bit.ly',
          'method': 'GET',
          'path': '/MyLinkCode',
          'scheme': 'https',
          'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
          'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
          'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,zh-TW;q=0.6,zh;q=0.5',
          'cookie': '_bit=l5ae7x-0b7f7cbf27f1ac7d41-00q',
          'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"',
          'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
          'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
          'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
          'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
          'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
          'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
          'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36}'}
sitetext = requests.get('ссылка на бит.лу', headers=header)
print(sitetext.headers)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что по умолчанию requests.get не ходит по редиректам. А если по редиректу не пойти, то и на Ваш сайт никто не попадет, и никакие счетчики на нем не отработают. А bit.ly и многие подобные сервисы их (редиректы) используют по полной. Но можно подсказать

```
sitetext = requests.get('ссылка на бит.лу', headers=header, allow_redirects=True)
```